# Android: How to call built-in copy or/and paste from a background service or from an activity?

Tags: android, clipboard

From a background service or from an activity, it is possible to call copy or/and paste system built-in functions?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You might find the article from the SDK documentation on the Clipboard Framework helpful as a starting point:

[The Clipboard Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html)

HTH

Comment: I already toolk a look at The Clipboard Framework but I dont found what I am looking for.

Comment: Then your question requires clarification ;)

Comment: for exemple when I am typing login on a web page, my service whould be able to call "paste" action to fill the login field.